# Firmware issues with HVR-950Q

Tags: firmware, tv-tuner

I am trying to install Hauppauge TV Tuner HVR-950Q on a system with Quantal 12.10.  I bought one of these cards about a year ago and it worked great.  I'm trying to install a 2nd tuner now and I can't get it to work.

Earlier I checked dmesg and it looked like it was a firmware issue.  I found [this post](http://ak33m.com/?p=211) and followed the directions.  It doesn't seem to have helped.

Now in the dmesg log it looks like it keeps trying to upload firmware...

Here's the relevant bit: 
[15174.768986] xc5000: waiting for firmware upload (dvb-fe-xc5000c-41.024.5.fw)...
[15174.776088] xc5000: Upload failed. (file not found?)

Does anyone have any suggestions?  I'm kind-of at my wit's end with this...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Relating to what version is required: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/3de5bffddbf5fa9d04f3d181dadcaedc1efa0158

Comment: Relating to the version that comes installed in Ubuntu at present: https://lists.debian.org/debian-kernel/2013/11/msg00088.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem starts here: [linuxtv.org/patch/13647](https://linuxtv.org/patch/13647/)

Where the correct firmware is stored on the web is not something I have yet discovered. In Mint 14 an even earlier firmware version is default.

Where it goes is: `lib/firmware`

Kirby

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution out of pure desperation with trial and error.
It works for me!!
Download the 4.1.30.7 version here:

http://www.kernellabs.com/firmware/xc5000/

put it in /lib/firmware and simply rename it to dvb-fe-xc5000c-41.024.5.fw or whatever dmesg is asking for.

Your card should now work!

Tested on Quantal with the 3.5.0 Kernel

Good Luck, Bernhard